# How can I proxy TCP connections from PGadmin to a TCP server?

Tags: postgresql, go, ssl, tcp, pgadmin

I have a TCP server in Go with TLS that I'm proxying a PGAdmin connection through to Postgres. The handshake is failing with the error `The first record does not look like a valid TLS handshake`.

I have SSLMode set to require in PGAdmin and I don't require mTLS, so no client cert on PGAdmin. The server also has `insecureSkipVerify` set to true since I'm testing locally with a self-signed cert.

I wrote a TCP client in Go that *does* work and can send bytes fine, so something tells me there is an issue with PGAdmin.

## Server Code

```
// generateTCPServer will accept external requests into the server over
// the TCP protocol
func (s *Server) generateTCPServer(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup, certs *TlsCerts) {

    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certs.TcpCert, certs.TcpKey)
    if err != nil {
        s.Logger.Fatal("Error loading TLS certificates", zap.Error(err))
    }

    config := tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}
    ln, err := tls.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%d", s.PublicPortTCP), &config)
    wg.Done()
    if err != nil {
        s.Logger.Fatal("Error generating TCP server", zap.Error(err))
    }
    defer ln.Close()

    s.Logger.Info("TCP server is listening", zap.Int("port", s.PublicPortTCP))

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            s.Logger.Error("Error accepting TCP connection", zap.Error(err))
            continue
        }

        tlsConn := conn.(*tls.Conn)

        err = tlsConn.Handshake()
        if err != nil {
            s.Logger.Error("Error performing TLS handshake", zap.Error(err))
            continue
        }

        state := tlsConn.ConnectionState()
        serverName := state.ServerName
        s.Logger.Info("Read TLS server name", zap.String("host", serverName))

        // handle incoming connection in a goroutine
        go s.handleExternalConnection(conn)
    }
}
```

I'm expecting PGAdmin to properly handle TLS over TCP, but I'm not seeing this is the case. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting any output in the `Logger` on your `Server` struct?

Comment: @Gavin I think what I'm seeing now is that Postgres has it's own wrapper around TLS, so this is not possible.